# Indirect Function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

```
 =Indirect("'App Summary'!"&$D$4&"18")
```

I have two worksheets, Sheet 1 and App Summary.  On Sheet 1 in cell D4 I have a column lookup based on a value typed in cell B2.   So for instance, if I type in July in cell B2 of Sheet 1, it will place H in cell D4 of Sheet 1.   If I type in June in cell B2 of Sheet 1, then it will place G in cell D4 of Sheet 1.   Using the above indirect formula, I look up a value in App Summary using the column reference in cell D4 on Sheet 1.

My question is the following.   Is there a way to make the above formula dynamic so that if I add a row to the App Summary sheet it will automatically adjust the row in the formula?  For instance in the above example lets say I am referencing H18 in the app summary sheet.  If I add a row in the app summary sheet just before H18, how do I get the formula on sheet 1 `=Indirect("'App Summary'!"&$D$4&"18")` to update to      `=Indirect("'App Summary'!"&$D$4&"19")` since the row it was referencing shifted down one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from *I am referencing H6 in another sheet* , the other sheet is `App Summary` use

```
=INDIRECT("'App Summary'!"&D3&ROW('App Summary'!$A$6))
```

Comment: what does the $A mean in your formula.  Does it mean I am referencing column A and row 6 in the App Summary sheet?

Comment: The `$` 's mean that the reference is **absolute** rather than **relative**.  Ie if you copy the formula to another cell, the reference to `$A$6` won't change (but the reference to `D3` will)  (Note, the reference _is_ to a cell on `App Summary` but not because of the `$`'s)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  After reading it, I'm not sure I explained what I am trying to do correctly.  I updated the post with additional details.

Comment: @user1609391 Having read your updated Q, that's exactly what my answer does.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can be certain that any additional rows in App Summary will be added as right-click and *Insert row*, then you could reference the a cell in the last row with an absolute reference (using dollar signs to fix the reference).

Another approach would be to convert your App Summary to an Excel table (ctrl + t) and then use [structured referencing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e). That way, you are not vulnerable to the changing structure of the App Summary sheet (except if you change column headings).